# Can't install STT from coqui ai with pip

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install stt package from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/stt/) and keep on getting this error. I am able to install all other packages except this one. Am I doing something wrong?

```
$ pip3 install stt

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement stt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for stt
```

Python & pip version

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 22.1 from /Users/vraj/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

$ python3 --version
Python 3.8.9
```

Comment: Is it MacOS X on M1? At https://pypi.org/project/stt/1.3.0/#files there is only one whell for Python 3.8 on MacOS X and it's not for M1, it's for AMD64: stt-1.3.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_10_**x86_64**.whl. For M1 you need to compile yourself: https://stt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/BUILDING.html

Comment: @phd Thanks a lot. I thought I was missing something.